# From SAS to Python : substr

Tags: python-2.7, sas

I would like to use the function `substr(my_var,1,2)` of SAS in Python. I tried a lot of functions like `contains()`, `split()` but it didn't work.

The functions `contains()` and `split()` work only for a string value. I would like to use it on a Python Series without using a `for`.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string in python can be [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) like any list:

```
>>> str = 'Hello World'
>>> str[1:3]
'el'
>>> str[1:-2]
'ello Wor'
```

To get substrings for multiple strings, you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> strs = ['Hello World', 'Foobar']
>>> [ str[1:4] for str in strs]
['ell', 'oob']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

In python, you may try this:

```
my_var[1:3]
```

This gets sub string of my_var from position 1 to 3 (exclusive).